# Do I need to make new interfaces every time in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to ask that do I need to create new `Interfaces` for every `POST` `GET` request I make which have different URL .
For ex 
I made 1 interface for register and other for Login other for getting Friends. Cant I just make 1 general post and get method where I can send URL , params to send and record response?

Comment: no need you can make only one interface for all your URL's

Comment: can you give me some example?

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: No you don't have to make multiple interfaces instead you have to make multiple ApiClient classes for different Url's

Comment: check this link https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: thanks thats a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No you don't need to create new interface or new client for each request!

Inside a interface you can create multiple method as you want and as your requirement.

For `Login` and fro `Registration` method name will be different, your parameter  will not same. So you can create method as you need.

```
//When Base Url like "http://exmaple.com/"

@GET("Service/registration")
Call<RegResult> getRegistered(@Query("name") String name,
   @Query("email") String email,
   @Query("dob") String dob,
   @Query("name") String name   

);

@GET("Service/login")
Call<LoginResult> getLogin(@Query("username") String username,
   @Query("pass") String pass  

);
@GET("Service/profile")
Call<ProfileResult> getProfile(@Query("userid") String userid

);
```

You can also use same client because your base url is same.

If base url is diffrent you can also use same client like this..

```
public class ApiClient {

 private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

 public static Retrofit getClient(String base_url) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(base_url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
 }
}
```

Now you can set different base url.

Creating object of interface...

```
String BASE_URL = "http://exmaple.com/";
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(ApiInterface.class);
```

Calling method..

```
 String user_id = "1";
 Call< ProfileResult > call = apiService.getProfile(user_id);
```

Getting result

```
call.enqueue(new Callback< ProfileResult >() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call< ProfileResult >call, Response< ProfileResult > response) {
            Profile profile = response.body().getResults();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call< ProfileResult >call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
 });
```

Hop you got your answer .... for farther query fill free to ask...